# How to delete duplicate rows but only for each products id

Tags: mysql

I would like to delete duplicate rows but only for each products id, below is my table data:

[image]

and the final result should be like below after run delete statement:

[image]

this is my query so far:

```
DELETE FROM `test` WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM `test` GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name)>1)
```

Comment: When you want to delete duplicate product ids, why does your wished result shows two entries of product id 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self join to delete duplicate rows based on same `product_id` and `name`

```
delete a
from test a
left join test b on a.product_id = b.product_id
                 and a.name = b.name
                 and a.id > b.id
where b.product_id is not null
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/REUV33630)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this. It's work for me.

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(a.id) FROM test a GROUP BY a.name)
```

Regard.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete t1 from test t1 join test t2 
on t1.name = t2.name and t1.product_id = t2.product_id and t1.id > t2.id;
```

**This works for me.**

I have done self join to find the repeated values.